# I got the wrong output in VBA - is my code wrong?

Tags: vba, finance

[image]

I wrote this code and the result is shown in the blue column.
`

```
Sub ematest()
'Calculate alpha for each periods
Dim alphas As Integer 'smoothing factor short moving average
Dim alphal As Integer 'smoothing factor long moving average

alphas = 2 / (Cells(3, 13).Value + 1)
alphal = 2 / (Cells(3, 14).Value + 1)

'Calculate 50 days Exponential MA

'calculate sema
For m = 53 To 6102
    Cells(m, 13) = (Cells(m, 5) * alphas) + ((1 - alphas) * Cells(m, 9)) 'for Column M
    
Next m

'calculate lema
For n = 203 To 6102
    Cells(n, 14) = (Cells(n, 5) * alphal) + ((1 - alphal) * Cells(n, 10)) 'for Column N
    
Next n

End Sub
```

`

I expect the result as shown in the yellow column where it is calculated by excel function for checking.

Am I missing something or have I make mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type being used is 'truncating' the results of your calculation.
Try using a data type of **Double** instead of **Integer**.

Run this code example to see the differences caused by the data type.

```
Sub ematestint()

Dim alphas As Integer 
Dim alphal As Integer 

alphas = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 13).Value)
alpha1 = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 14).Value)

alphas = alphas + 1
alpha1 = alpha1 + 1

alphas = 2 / alphas
alpha1 = 2 / alpha1

MsgBox "alphas = " & alphas & vbCrLf & "alpha1 =" & alpha1

End Sub


Sub ematestdbl()

Dim alphas As Double 
Dim alpha1 As Double 

alphas = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 13).Value)
alpha1 = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 14).Value)

alphas = alphas + 1
alpha1 = alpha1 + 1

alphas = 2 / alphas
alpha1 = 2 / alpha1


MsgBox "alphas = " & alphas & vbCrLf & "alpha1 =" & alpha1


End Sub
```